# Updating object and persisting

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vuejs2

i have this object:

[image]

and i want to update each student on object, each student is with an unique index (id from database), so i can send that object to the server later, this is how i´ve tried:

studentID = param (integer) 
notes = param (object)

the function is call every time i change an input in the form

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.studentNotes[studentID].desempenos.length; i++) {
    if (this.studentNotes[studentID].desempenos[i].desempeno === desempeno) {
        this.studentNotes[studentID].desempenos[i].nota = notes.nota;
    }
}
```

The problem is this:
I enter the values for the index 190 and it saves, but when i want to save the values for other index, let's say 191, it overrides the value from 190.

i can't figure it out why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `desempenos[i].nota = notes.nota` it should be one reference, try  `Object.entries(notes.nota).forEach(item => { this.studentNotes[studentID].desempenos[i].nota[item[0]] = item[1]})`

Comment: hi, notes is an object passed like a param. i updated my question

Comment: check this [Javascript Reference vs value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: wow didn't know about this, thanks man